# Printing numbers from a for loop horizontally instead of vertically

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project where I have to use a loop to print the numbers 1 through 10 and 1 through 200. I have created both loops and both loops print all numbers as required. However, I am struggling on trying to figure out how to make the numbers print horizontally instead of vertically. For example:

Instead of having the numbers print out like this

1

2

3

The numbers should print like this
1 2 3

Furthermore, I am also trying to avoid having a horizontal scroll bar. The loop that prints all numbers from 1 to 200 can be on multiple horizontal lines.

The code I have so far is

```
<h1>Counting With Loops!</h1>

<script>
  for (counter=1; counter <=10; counter++) {
    document.write(counter + "<br>")
  }
</script>

<br><br>

<script>
  for (counter=1; counter <=200; counter++) {
    document.write(counter + "<br>")
  }
</script>
```

I have tried removing the `<br>` element, which puts all of the numbers on the same line, but does not leave any spaces between them. It also creates a horizontal scroll bar for the 1 through 200 loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<br>` tag creates a new line, just replace it with a single space `" "`:

```html
 <script>
      for (counter=1; counter <=200; counter++) {
        document.write(counter + "  ")
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some css into it by defining a width of a div and let the css handle the new line.

```
<style>
div {
  width: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>
 
<h1>Counting With Loops!</h1>

<div id="block"></div>

<script>
   for (counter=1; counter <=210; counter++) {
    document.getElementById("block").write(counter + " ")
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

flexbox is great for this kind of thing.

```js
var ten = '';
  for (counter=1; counter <=10; counter++) {
    ten = ten + ' ' + counter;
  }
  document.getElementById('ten').textContent = ten;



  var hundred = '';
  for (counter=1; counter <=200; counter++) {
   hundred = hundred + ' ' +  counter;   
  }
  document.getElementById('hundred').textContent = hundred;
```

```css
#container{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<h1>Counting With Loops!</h1>
<div id='container'>
 <p id='ten'></p>
 <p id='hundred'></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[You'd better not use `document.write`](https://blog.dareboost.com/en/2016/09/avoid-using-document-write-scripts-injection/). It's pretty simple to create an element and print your results in there. Furthermore, first aggregating the results in memory, then print will  make your scripting a lot faster. Here's an example:

```js
// first create an array
let resultsArray = [];

// fill the array with numbers 0 - 199
for (let i=0; i < 200; i += 1) {
  resultsArray.push(i);
}

// print it to pre#log
document.querySelector("#log").textContent = resultsArray.join(" ");
```

```css
#log {
  /* this creates the wrapping */
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<pre id="log"></pre>
```